# keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri in quasar with ios

Tags: vue.js, keycloak, hybrid-mobile-app, quasar-framework

**I am facing an issue to redirect keycloak sso to a mobile app (android or ios)**

Answer (score 1):

@flavio.donze
I have same issue when redirect login (not logout)

- If I put scheme (ex: `com.application.example://` ) in "**Valid Redirect URIs**" and "**Base URL**", keycloak admin console gives "`A redirect URI is not a valid URI`", only accept **http/https** scheme
- If I add redirect_uri into login link (ex: `https://{{keycloak-server}}/auth/realms/employee/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=mobile-app&redirect_uri=com.application.example%3A%2F%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid` ), I got message "`Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`"

Answer (score 0):

If you are the admin of the service and recently updated keycloak to version 18.0.0 or above, this might be the reason/solution:

**Solution**

> If your application directly uses links to logout endpoint with the
> `redirect_uri` parameter, you may be required to change this as
> described above. Consider either removing the `redirect_uri` parameter
> entirely or replacing it with the `id_token_hint` and
> `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameters.

**Reason**

> Previous versions of Keycloak had supported automatic logout of the
> user and redirecting to the application by opening logout endpoint URL
> such as
> http(s)://example-host/auth/realms/my-realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri.
> While that implementation was easy to use, it had potentially negative
> impact on performance and security. The new version has better support
> for logout based on the OpenID Connect RP-Initiated Logout
> specification. The parameter redirect_uri is no longer supported;
> also, in the new version, the user needs to confirm the logout. It is
> possible to omit the confirmation and do automatic redirect to the
> application when you include parameter post_logout_redirect_uri
> together with the parameter id_token_hint with the ID Token used for
> login.

**Source**

https://www.keycloak.org/2022/04/keycloak-1800-released#_openid_connect_logout